# responsive submenu open on click not working

Tags: javascript

I have converted my first HTML to WordPress website and have a responsive sub menu which is not opening properly on mobile because obviously there is no hover functionality. I have looked up solutions and have come to nothing as my JavaScript knowledge is non existent therefore copying and pasting code from examples on here is not getting me the result I want to achieve.

The menu I am trying to fix is on the following website:

https://www.piogroup.in/wordpress/

I have 2 parents which are "about" and "products" and they are not clickable links. So far I have tried the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#menu-item-74").off("click").on("click", function() {
    $(".sub-menu").fadeToggle("slow");
});
})

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#menu-item-72").off("click").on("click", function() {
    $(".sub-menu").fadeToggle("slow");
});
})
```

and then added this as well:

```
var $handle = $('.sub-menu').prev();

var opened = 0;
$handle.on('click', function(e){

  if (opened) {
window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
  } else {
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
$('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
opened = 1;
}
});

$('html').on('click', function(){
  if (opened) {
$('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
opened = 0;
}
   });
```

I am not sure if I am meant to put up any other files but can do so.

Comment: Read through http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, regarding your javascript you have provided what is needed, but i am missing some html-code. Withouth the HTML-code i can not reproduce your problem. A good tip (which many will ask for) is to create a https://jsfiddle.net/. In it you can supply html and javascript code, but make sure it is a little as possible but still recreates your problem. Otherwise it is a good question.

Comment: `.off("click")` may produce error or `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

@R Alexander if I understand you correctly, Your sub menu is not working on mobile devices. Below code may be help you out.

```
minWidth = $(window).width();

if(winWidth < 768){
$(".menu-main-menu-container li").click(function(){
   $(".menu-main-menu-container li ul").slideToggle();
   $(".menu-main-menu-container li ul").parent().siblings().children(".menu-main-menu-container li ul").slideUp();
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I went through your code and there are some logical inconsistencies.

First of all you should change this as follows:

```
var $handle = $('.sub-menu').prev();

var opened = 0;
$handle.on('click', function(e) {

  if (opened) {
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
  } else {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
    opened = 1;
  }
});
```

This makes the particular clicked element to `slideToggle` instead of all the `.sub-menu` elements.

Then to emulate the closing of the drop downs use this:

```
$('html').on('click', function() {
  if (opened) {
    $('.sub-menu').slideUp();
    opened = 0;
  }
});
```